# easy regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace string:

```
@a @a /@a @a
```

on

```
5 5 /@a 5
```

What I've tried so far:

```
import re

txt = "@a @a /@a @a"
x = re.sub("????", "5", txt)

print(x)
```

What the regular exception will work?

Thanks !

Comment: Will you clarify your question, please? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: "Do my work for me" isn't what StackOverflow is for. What, *exactly*, is your byte-for-byte input? What, *exactly*, is your desired byte-for-byte output? What have you tried already?

Comment: Some context would be nice. Is this the only string you'll ever the regex on? Also, if you don't know a lick of regex, you should learn at least the basics. If you know this is an "easy regular expression" why don't you research a little bit of regex and understand it instead of asking us to do your work for you

Comment: Writing ???? for your regex isn't something you've "tried so far". Have you actually tried some regex or are you just asking for someone to do your homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the negative lookbehind regex to help you. Here you can use this regex:

```
(?<!/)@a
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gZ1oV2/2)**

[image]